# Starting stunnel with systemd

Tags: debian, systemd, stunnel

I have a Debian 11 system on the VPS with stunnel to wrap SSH (don't ask why).

I have a configuration file `/etc/stunnel/proxy-ssh.conf`:

```
[proxy-ssh]
cert = /etc/ssl/private/le-vps1.merlin-vrn.tk-key+fullchain.pem
accept = 1443
connect = 22
```

If I start it by hand, it starts:

```
# ss -lnpt | grep -c 1443
0
# stunnel /etc/stunnel/proxy-ssh.conf
# ss -lnpt | grep 1443
LISTEN 0      128                 0.0.0.0:1443       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("stunnel",pid=10121,fd=10))
```

`syslog` contains the following:

```
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: stunnel 5.56 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Running  with OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6,SYSTEMD TLS:ENGINE,FIPS,OCSP,PSK,SNI Auth:LIBWRAP
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/proxy-ssh.conf
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: UTF-8 byte order mark not detected
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: FIPS mode disabled
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Configuration successful
Oct 11 09:12:02 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Binding service [proxy-ssh] to :::1443: Address already in use (98)
Oct 11 09:12:24 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[0]: Service [proxy-ssh] accepted connection from xx.xx.xxx.xx:51104
Oct 11 09:12:24 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[0]: s_connect: connected ::1:22
Oct 11 09:12:24 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[0]: Service [proxy-ssh] connected remote server from ::1:59156
Oct 11 09:12:25 vps1 systemd[1]: Started Session 73843673 of user yyyy.
```

So it works (you can see it accepted a connection). I'ts unclear why it says `Binding service [proxy-ssh] to :::1443: Address already in use (98)`, when `ss` clearly shows nothing is listening on the port 1443, but this doesn't impede its operation.

---

Debian ships a systemd template unit `stunnel@.service`. I supposed to enable and start a service `stunnel@proxy-ssh.service` to run stunnel with my config file `proxy-ssh.conf`, so I kill stunnel started by hand and run the service:

```
# systemctl status stunnel@proxy-ssh.service
● stunnel@proxy-ssh.service - TLS tunnel for network daemons - per-config-file service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/stunnel@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2023-10-11 09:26:36 +04; 4min 55s ago
       Docs: man:stunnel4(8)
    Process: 10314 ExecStart=/usr/bin/stunnel4 /etc/stunnel/proxy-ssh.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 10314 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
root@vps1:/var/log# ss -lnpt | grep -c 1443
0
root@vps1:/var/log# systemctl start stunnel@proxy-ssh.service
root@vps1:/var/log# ss -lnpt | grep -c 1443
0
```

`syslog` has the following:

```
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 systemd[1]: Started TLS tunnel for network daemons - per-config-file service.
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: stunnel 5.56 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu platform
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Running  with OpenSSL 1.1.1w  11 Sep 2023
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6,SYSTEMD TLS:ENGINE,FIPS,OCSP,PSK,SNI Auth:LIBWRAP
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Reading configuration from file /etc/stunnel/proxy-ssh.conf
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: UTF-8 byte order mark not detected
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: FIPS mode disabled
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Configuration successful
Oct 11 09:32:03 vps1 stunnel: LOG5[ui]: Binding service [proxy-ssh] to :::1443: Address already in use (98)
Oct 11 09:33:33 vps1 systemd[1]: stunnel@proxy-ssh.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Oct 11 09:33:33 vps1 systemd[1]: stunnel@proxy-ssh.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Notice the 1.5 min delay after "normal initialization sequence" and before it's declared failed. During that delay the service is translating through some states, I happened to catch it in the state: `Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Wed 2023-10-11 09:32:03 +04; 43s ago`. Finally it arrives into the failed state:

```
● stunnel@proxy-ssh.service - TLS tunnel for network daemons - per-config-file service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/stunnel@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2023-10-11 09:33:33 +04; 5min ago
       Docs: man:stunnel4(8)
    Process: 10546 ExecStart=/usr/bin/stunnel4 /etc/stunnel/proxy-ssh.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 10546 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The service file doesn't have anything fancy; it's the same command I use to start it.

What's wrong with it and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out now it requires stunnel to be configured to run in foreground:

```
foreground = yes

[proxy-ssh]
cert = /etc/ssl/private/le-vps1.merlin-vrn.tk-key+fullchain.pem
accept = 1443
connect = 22
```

After that the service started immediately and works as expected.